# Change fields of documents in a collection Firestore periodically - Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a database structure like this:

Posts(collection) -> userID (document) -> Subposts (subcollection) -> document[isVisible: true]

We have different userIDs which means that each userID has a subcollection of different posts.

I want to set up a cloud function which periodically (every 2 minutes) checks all the documents in all the sub collections (Subposts) and if the field `isVisible` is `true`, then changes it to `false`.

This is what I did:

```
exports.changeIsVisibleFieldAfterDay = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun((context) => {
      db.collection("Posts/{uid}/Subposts").get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.data().isVisible == true) {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.update({isVisible: false}));
        }
      });
    });
```

I've set up the {uid} wildcard because I need to check in each document subcollection (Subposts).

This implementation doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For firestore query you must provide valid documentID.

If you wish to check for all users subcollections, there are few other ways to get it done!

1. Using collection query

- Query the `Posts` collection >  iterate over the users
- Query `Subposts` with valid doc ID for each user  >  iterate over the subpost documents
- Update the doc with `{isVisible: false}` based on condition

2. Using [collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query

- Use collectionGroup query on `Subposts` collection. This will return all subPosts of each user
- iterate over the document and update with `{isVisible: false}` based on condition

In your iteration snippet, the collection query returns `QuerySnapshot` and in this the iteration should be on the field `docs`, like below

```
snap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    if (doc.data().isVisible == true) {
        doc.update({ isVisible: false });
    }
});
```

Note: I prefer to go with async/await with `for..loop` instead of `.then()`, as `forEach` won't give expected result with their inner `await` calls.

Comment: Thank you, if the Posts and Subposts collection remain fixed, but the documentID behind them changes how can I implement a collection group query?
Is this the right implementation?

const querySnapshot = await db.collectionGroup('Subposts').where('isVisible', '==', 'true').get();
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
});
Will this take a look at all subcollections (Subposts) no matter the parent document userId?

Comment: Ok I'll test it later and mark the answer as correct if it works